# WSO2 AM 1.10.0 cannot be accessed in public

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have `WSO2 AM (1.10.0)` installed on a production server within my organization and this server is allowed to be accessed in public by removing firewall. However it is only available in organization's intranet like browsing to the URL  https://puaki.mpi.govt.nz/api/mrldatabase/v1/countries and will get following data,

```
[
   {
      "countryCode":"AUS",
      "countryName":"Australia"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"CAN",
      "countryName":"Canada"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"CHN",
      "countryName":"China"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"CDX",
      "countryName":"Codex"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"EEC",
      "countryName":"European Union"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"HKG",
      "countryName":"Hong Kong"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"IND",
      "countryName":"India"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"IDN",
      "countryName":"Indonesia"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"ISR",
      "countryName":"Israel"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"JPN",
      "countryName":"Japan"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"KOR",
      "countryName":"Korea"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"MAL",
      "countryName":"Malaysia"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"NCL",
      "countryName":"New Caledonia"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"NZL",
      "countryName":"New Zealand"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"RUS",
      "countryName":"Russian Federation"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"SGP",
      "countryName":"Singapore"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"SAF",
      "countryName":"South Africa"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"CHE",
      "countryName":"Switzerland"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"TWN",
      "countryName":"Taiwan"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"THA",
      "countryName":"Thailand"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"USA",
      "countryName":"United States"
   },
   {
      "countryCode":"VNM",
      "countryName":"Vietnam"
   }
]
```

When trying to exacly the same thing from extranet, I got the following error

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I was wondering if there are filters on the `API Manager` to prevent extenal connections (as the traffic is getting to the server but being rejected)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there are filters on the API Manager to prevent
>   extenal connections (as the traffic is getting to the server but being
>   rejected)?

There aren't any such filters in API Manager. You should check your firewall policies and ports.

Comment: Thanks your response. I will contact system engineer to check the sever settings.